# What's the best way to create a frame with a fixed interior dimension and fluid exterior dimension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I plan on creating a layer of absolutely positioned elements that is moved around with jQuery. I need to create a frame, on top of and around this layer, that has a fixed viewport in the center and edges which flow to the edges of the browser viewport, creating a mask that hides portions of the main layer that is moved around underneath.

Currently I am using four divs to create the frame and setting their dimensions onload with a jQuery statement like this:

```
`$("#viewportLeft,#viewportRight").css("width",($(window).width()-[maskViewportWidth])/2);`
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: did you get it working? if so can you post an example of it working (maybe on js fiddle or something).  I'm think'n there may be a css solution but I need to see in action what you are trying to accomplish. because you could get 100% width and height using css depending on exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8VRT5/

So the goal is for those viewport divs to create an opening of a fixed size in the center, while filing the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just move a div around inside another div?

Comment: If I did that, as far as I can tell, I wouldn't have a layer of elements acting as a mask to cover the hidden portions of the layer which moves underneath.

Comment: That's right but perhaps explain the purpose because I'd assumed that this answer would solve your problem.